# I'm trying to understand how this regular expression in Perl creates what it does

Tags: regex, perl

$row contains

```
&lt;img alt="1688.jpg" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg" /&gt;
```

After I execute the following statement

```
$row =~ s/("(.+?)")(.+?)("(.+?)")/""$3$1/;
```

`$row` contains `&lt;img alt="" src="1688.jpg" /&gt;`

Which is exactly what I want though I can't figure out how the regex manages to populate the following.

```
$1 -> "1688.jpg"<br>
$2 -> 1688.jpg<br>
$3 ->  src= (it has a leading space)<br>
$4 -> "http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg"<br>
$5 -> http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg<br>
```

I figure it wouldn't have taken me nearly so long to get it to work if I could have understood just how it was populating the variable. Might someone be so kind as to explain it to me?

Comment: Please use inline code markup for the HTML tags and variable names in your prose. I was going to fix it, but I don't know if your input is `<img` or `&lt;img`.

Comment: Try using the `re 'debug'` pragma. http://perldoc.perl.org/re.html#'debug'-mode or put your pattern into http://regex101.com

Answer (score 4):

The capture groups are numbered starting from the leftmost to the rightmost (ignore the fact that some are nested). Given your input, the capture groups are numbered as follows:

`$row =~ s/("(.+?)")(.+?)("(.+?)")/""$3$1/;
           1 2      3    4 5`

Also, the `?` after the `.+` means it will match the minimum it can to satisfy the pattern, in this case it will match up to the first double quote it finds. So we can see that it captures the following (ignore the single quotes):

1. '"1688.jpg"'
2. '1688.jpg'
3. ' src='
4. '"http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg"'
5. 'http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg'

Because this is a string substitution, the entire section of the input that was matched will be replaced by the second part of the regex pattern (i.e. `""$3$1`). So we will replace (from the first double quote to the last double quote) this:

`"1688.jpg" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg"`

with:
`"" src="1688.jpg"`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Just start counting the groups starting from the left parenthesis to see what gets captured.  Here is a slightly annotated version:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $row = '<img alt="1688.jpg" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg" />';

#           1 2   2 13   34 5   5 4
my $re = qr/("(.+?)")(.+?)("(.+?)")/;

#          12      213   345                                                             54
# <img alt="1688.jpg" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg" />';

$row =~ $re;
print "\n";
print "\$1 => '$1'\n";
print "\$2 => '$2'\n";
print "\$3 => '$3'\n";
print "\$4 => '$4'\n";
print "\$5 => '$5'\n";

$row =~ s/$re/""$3$1/;
print $row . "\n";
```

**Output**

```
$1 => '"1688.jpg"'
$2 => '1688.jpg'
$3 => ' src='
$4 => '"http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg"'
$5 => 'http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg'
<img alt="" src="1688.jpg" />
```

Comment: Chris & xxfelixxx, Response most appreciated as the regex and variables make sense and I realize I could have gotten by with...

$row =~ s/"(.+?)"(.+?)"(.+?)"/""$2"$1"/;

Answer (score 0):

As people have explained well before me, each time you use brackets you create a capture group.

I find the best way to prevent confusion or having to count brackets is to explicitly not capture the stuff you don't need by putting `?:` after the opening bracket.

```
use Data::Dumper;

my $s = '<img alt="1688.jpg" src="http://res.cloudinary.com/stw/image/upload/v1478118784/1688.jpg" />';

my @row = $s =~ /("(.+?)")(.+?)("(.+?)")/;

# only capture quoted things
my @row1 = $s =~ /(?:"(.+?)")(?:.+?)(?:"(.+?)")/;

print Dumper \@row;
print Dumper \@row1;
```